# Archiving model data in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I am working with a django app that grew more than I expected and now need to archive some data so it doesn't slow down eventual queries. My question is, what is the best way to archive an existing model? Here is what I have thought so far:

1 - Create an inherited model:

```
class OriginalModel(models.Model):
    ...
    field = models.CharField(etc...)
    ...

class ArchivedModel(OriginalModel):
    pass
```

2 - Create a post_save method so whenever something is saved to my original model it will create an archived instance as well.

3 - Create a purge task with celery on my original model to keep only the relevant data.

I am not sure however if model inheritance will work as I expect it though. If anyone has some input on this I will greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The best solution depends on the specific details of your project. Once I did it like the accepted answer says. It complicated a whole slew of things in Django's views. Something as banal as trying to find a record through the admin interface: if the record is archived, then I have to search in the archive, if not, then I search in the main table. Oh, this is surmountable alright but this split at the ORM level soon creeps everywhere. I've eventually reverted to just one table as the project matured. Performance issues like the one you mention should be solved at the DB level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code data from `ArchivedModel` will stay in `OriginalModel` SQL table. At SQL level `ArchivedModel` will be a table with single `id` field referencing to `OriginalModel` table.  So if you will add objects to `ArchivedModel` in `post_save` signal they will be duplicated in `OriginalModel` :-)

You need to create [abstract base class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) and inherit both "real" models from it:

```
class AbstractModel(models.Model):
    ...
    field = models.CharField(etc...)
    ...
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class OriginalModel(AbstractModel):
    pass

class ArchivedModel(AbstractModel):
    pass
```

In this case `OriginalModel` and `ArchivedModel` will have different SQL tables with the same set of fields.