# Archiving data in Django like a magic?

Tags: django, archive

My project has a lot of models.

Each model has a field is_active that is True when in production and False when it is completed or not used .

Is there any default magic solution for this with Django? 
I have about 40-60 models so ideally it should be one solution covers all.

I found this answer [Archiving model data in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713026/archiving-model-data-in-django)  that requires development effort for each model individually and this will create lot of models.

Any Magic Alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve this problem with [Abstract Model Inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes).

This will allow you to write logic for one class and set of fields and it will apply to all child classes.

```
class IsActive(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def toggle_active(self):
        self.is_active = !self.is_active

class Child(IsActive):
    # This object now has `is_active` and `toggle_active` fields.
```